# 'Could not find Developer Disk Image' message from XCode when I run the built PhoneGap app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ant, phonegap-desktop-app

I made my first app using PhoneGap, and have built it for iOS. I have Java and Ant properly installed and the XCode project has been apparently created. I open it in XCode and I can build it as well, from XCode. When I run it it says that error message? What seems to be problem here? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xCode version is too old. Probably you updated the phone's OS to a newer version. Usually for each version of iOS there is a version of xCode, and if the OS is newer than xCode you get this error.

Comment: XCode v7.2.1 I don't think it's too old.

Comment: The iOS is latest - v9.3

Comment: You need xCode 7.3

Comment: The problem is (as I have just found out) my old apps aren't running as well, and throw the same error!!! So the issue is new XCode. I shouldn't have installed it.

Comment: I don't think so. For iOS 9.3 you need xCode 7.3

Comment: Well it has nothing to do with your apps. It has to do with your DEVICE. Try running your apps on a DEVICE with an older OS version and you will see that all your apps will work.

Comment: Nah, I ran it on a simulator and it went fine.

Comment: Yeah, becaus xCode 7.2.1 has simulators with iOS 9.2.1 not 9.3

Comment: Ok, that's probably it then. I will try and install new XCode, see how it goes. I can't do it apparently. I have Yosemite. Maybe I will install El Capitan and retry.

Comment: I installed El Capitan and on top of that I installed XCode 7.3, and now it works like a charm. Thanks!